# Encontrar o maior palíndromo feito a partir do produto de dois números de 3 dígitos - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmo

Estou com um problema. Estou criando um algoritmo em Python para achar o maior palíndromo feito a partir do produto de dois números de 3 dígitos.

Código:

```
i = 0
while i <= 999:
    temp = str(i * 999)
    tempInverso = temp[::-1]
    if temp == tempInverso:
        pol = int(temp)    
    i += 1
print(pol)
```

Ele me retorna o valor `90909`, porém o valor correto é `906609`. 
Como não acho nada de errado com o código, vim buscar ajuda de vocês. Agradeço a atenção de todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este daqui funciona:

```
i = 0
j = 0
pol = 0
while i <= 999:
    j = i
    while j <= 999:
        temp = str(i * j)
        tempInverso = temp[::-1]
        if temp == tempInverso:
            polTemp = int(temp)
            if polTemp > pol:
                pol = polTemp
        j += 1
    i += 1
print(pol)
```

Observe que há dois laços aqui. O motivo é porque o que você fazia, você tinha `i * 999`, ou seja, você estava procurando o maior múltiplo de 999 que fosse palíndrome, e não o maior produto de dois números de até três dígitos que fosse palíndrome.

Para fazer com dois números, uso `i * j`, onde uso um laço dentro do outro, um percorrendo os valores de `i` e outro os valores de `j`. O valor de `j` é inicializado com `j = i` ao invés de `j = 0` porque uma vez que a multiplicação é comutativa, os valores de `j` que forem menores do que `i` são repetidos e portanto desnecessários de serem testados.

Um outro problema que você tinha é que você ao encontrar um palíndrome, já o atribuía à variável `pol`, sem verificar se esse palíndrome é melhor que o anterior já encontrado. Como resultado, ele mostraria o último palíndrome encontrado, e não o maior palíndrome. A solução para isso foi usar uma variável `polTemp` e só atribuí-la à `pol` se `polTemp > pol`.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](http://ideone.com/UU5l3M)

Comment: Funcionou sem problemas obrigado!

Comment: Agora que você comentou eu percebi a besteira que estava fazendo buscando apenas nos múltiplos de 999.

Comment: Os contadores `i` e `j` podem começar em 100, tendo em vista que deve ser considerado apenas o produto de números de 3 dígitos.

Comment: @BrunoSantos Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, peço que marque-a como aceita/correta ao clicar no ✅ abaixo do número da votação.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Isso é discutível, uma vez que 012 pode ou não ser considerado um número de três dígitos.

Comment: Discordo. Matematicamente falando mesmo o valor 012 possui dois dígitos.  Estamos trabalhando com números, não strings.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Por isso que eu disse que é discutível, dá para argumentar tanto contra quanto a favor e depende do contexto desejado. Entretanto, esse programa funciona independente de qual seja a interpretação dada para "número de três dígitos".

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução possível:

```
from itertools import product

palindromes = (i*j for i, j in product(range(100, 1000), repeat=2) if str(i*j) == str(i*j)[::-1])

print("O maior palíndromo encontrado foi", max(palindromes))
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/IYiyJi).

A função `product(range(100, 1000), repeat=2)` irá gerar todas as combinações de valores dois a dois entre 100 e 999. É feito um laço de repetição sobre esta lista, armazenando o primeiro valor em `i` e o segundo em `j`. É retornado para a lista final o valor `i*j` se a condição `str(i*j) == str(i*j)[::-1]` for verdadeira. Com isso, `palindromes` será um *generator* com todos os palíndromos resultado do produto entre dois valores de três dígitos. Com a função `max` obtemos o maior deles.

Comment: Obrigado pela sua ajuda !